# Unable to convert a string to Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IconElement

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I couldn't find how to use the [SymbolIcon.Symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon.symbol.aspx) to change an appbar icon...

This is to understand what I need to do:

```
if (SecondaryTile.Exists(ItemId))
{
    PinToStart.Icon = "UnPin"; //instead of "Pin"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tha `AppBarButton`'s [Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.icon.aspx) is `IconElement` type so you cannot just put there a `string`. If you want to use a [Symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx) you can do it like this:

```
PinToStart.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.UnPin); //instead of "Pin"
```

But I've encountered some problems while exchanging only Icons. I'm not sure if they are still there after some updates. If they are, I suggest to exchange the whole `AppBarButton

```
private AppBarButton pin
{
    get
    {
       AppBarButton temp = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Pin) };
       temp.Label = "Pin";
       temp.Click += Pin_Click;
       return temp;
    }
}

private AppBarButton unPin
{
    get
    {
       AppBarButton temp = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.UnPin) };
       temp.Label = "UnPin";
       temp.Click += UnPin_Click;
       return temp;
    }
}
```

Then in the code exchange like this:

```
(BottomAppBar as CommandBar).PrimaryCommands[0] = pin; // assign the whole button when Pin/unPin
```

Comment: Ok, the first solution seems to work, or I could just make two buttons in XAML and 
if (SecondaryTile.Exists(ItemId))
{
    PinToStart.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    UnpinFromStart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

Comment: @user3393663 Nah, right - I've assumed that you were asking about Application Bar Button :). As you are running normal Button in XAML, then forget about the second part, as you have said the first part is sufficient. Changing Visibility should work. Note also that you can define Button's Contetnt as `SymbolIcon` then there is no need to set it from code.

Comment: Yes, they are AppBarButtons :). Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use SymbollIcon from xaml & how?

Comment: @shamimreza You can normally put `<SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept"/>` in xaml.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to add it for my silverlight project. may be SymbolIcon is supported for wp8.1(runtime only).

Comment: @shamimreza Yes it's not available in Silverlight - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1, there are no Symbol means `'UnPin'`.

But you can make you `Pin Button` as **AppBarToggleButton**. When it has pinned, you can make `'Pin Button'` **Checked**. And when it has not pinned, you can make `'Pin Button'` **UnChecked**.